# How to flatten a list of lists?

Tags: python

How to flatten a list of lists in more pythonic way? 
This is the code I tried.

```py
input, output = [[1,2], [3, 4]], []

for e in input:
    output.extend(e)  

print output # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Is it code that you yourself wrote?

Comment: Why you think above code is not pythonic? Though I suggest one improvement, just initializes `input` and `output` on different lines for better readability.

Comment: Can you please rename the title to be more meaningful. Example: "Flattening a list of lists"

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I have renamed my title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @MateuszKonieczny notes, you 100% should be using Python 3, not Python 2. In particular, that means instead of `print output`, you use `print(output)`. When googling for docs or tutorials use "python3" instead of "python" and that should give you what you need.

I wouldn't use tuple unpacking like you did in your first line:

```py
input, output = [[1,2], [3, 4]], []
```

Tuple unpacking is a fantastic and powerful feature, but here it makes you have to squint and count brackets to see which thing is being assigned to `output` (since `,` can occur within a list). Tuple unpacking is great for naming functions that return multiple values:

```py
fastest_runtime, average_runtime = run_benchmarks()
```

But in this case, put assignments on separate lines. Also, take care to properly PEP8 by putting spaces around commas. Formatting is a key part of pythonic code. You also shouldn't use `input` as it shadows the builtin function `input`.

```py
lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
output = []
```

Now, I'll make a bold claim that almost any time you initialize an empty list and then proceed to call `append()` or `extend()` on it, you're doing something wrong. Often, such constructions can be much more concisely and clearly be expressed as a list/generator expression (I've also renamed `output` to `flattened`, because the operation you are doing is a common functional one called [flattening](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Python)..although don't look at any of the Python snippets on that page, they are horrible):

```py
flattened = [x for l in lists for x in l]
```

This is a very common Python idiom. Sometimes you may see:

```py
flattened = sum(lists, [])
```

This is a trick that takes advantage of the fact that `[1, 2] + [3, 4] == [1, 2, 3, 4]` (addition is overloaded for lists). Whether it reads better than the list expression is debatable, but it is common nonetheless.

Also note that `extend` certainly has its place in many applications. It's just in this particular one, the above patterns are typically preferred (due to their brevity).

Answer (score 3):

To complete the alternate ways to achieve what you are doing (flattening a list of lists into a single list), there is [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

lists = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
output = list(chain.from_iterable(lists))
```

This is not so useful in this particular case (at least it is not really better than the alternatives), but it can be if you only need to iterate over the output once (since it is a generator). This allows you to not store the flattened list in memory.

```
for x in chain.from_iterable(lists):
    print(x)
```